# Calling a singleton method within an instance method in a module that extends itself

Tags: ruby

I extended `Kernel` by itself, and within the definition of the instance method `Kernel#abort`, I called the singleton method `Kernel.abort`:

```
module Kernel
  extend self

  def abort
    puts "Press ENTER to exit..."
    gets
    Kernel.abort
  end
end

abort
```

When I call `Kernel#abort`, it seems that the `Kernel.abort` call inside the method definition refers to the original `Kernel#abort` (extended as `Kernel.abort`).

How does Ruby know that when I write `Kernel.abort`, I mean the original `abort` method, not the one I just created? How would I recursively call the new `abort` method I just created?

Comment: If you want recursion, use `abort` instead of `Kernel.abort`.

Comment: `abort` is a call with implicit `self`. `Kernel` in `Kernel.abort` is the explicit `self`, you specify the object that the method should be called on. Oh, and I reopened your question.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how name resolution works here, so I'm not posting an answer. This question must have been asked already on this site, though :)

Comment: also i think you could have just called super like `def exit { message; super }`

Comment: @kimmmo: nope, there's no `super` there.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I put the above in a file, follow it with `Kernel.abort` and do `ruby the_file.rb`, it does abort (exit status 1) but the code in the redefined version doesn't run. Ruby 2.2.4. Could you show more context?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth: do `abort` instead of `Kernel.abort` :)

Comment: I had complete code but it was edited just a moment ago. I am not sure if I am supposed to edit the question back.

Comment: Re latest question title edit - I am not sure it's correct. There are no classes here involved, only modules, right?

Comment: yeah, you can't extend with classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Kernel.abort` is defined by first defining an instance method `Kernel#abort` and then making it also a singleton method with `module_function`. ([This is definitely the case in Rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/v3.14/kernel/common/kernel.rb#L214); I couldn't find it in the MRI source but see below.) [`module_function` *makes a copy* of the method.](https://practicingruby.com/articles/uses-for-modules-3a) When you redefine `abort` you redefine the instance method but not the singleton copy.

`Object` includes `Kernel`, so when you say `abort` you get the instance method, which you've redefined, but when you say `Kernel.abort` you get the singleton method, which you haven't redefined.

If you really wanted to use recursion in `abort`, or just to demonstrate that this explanation is correct, call `module_function :abort` after redefining the method. The singleton method will be updated to be the same as the instance method and both methods will recurse.

Note that you didn't need to `extend self` to redefine the instance version of `abort`. Since `Kernel` is already included in `Object`, you only needed to redefine the instance method for all objects to see the redefined version. On the other hand, if `Kernel` had used `extend self` to expose `#abort` in the first place, we could redefine it without any complications.

The following demonstrates that the lack of recursion happens with user-defined, pure Ruby methods, i.e. that `module_function` is responsible and native methods are not:

```
$ cat foo.rb
module Foo
  def bar
    puts "old version"
  end
  module_function :bar
end

module Foo
  def bar
    puts "new version"
    Foo.bar
  end
end

Object.include Foo
bar
$ ruby foo.rb
new version
old version
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll read all 3 articles of uses of modules, then come back to this question.

Comment: Got distracted with work, forgot about this question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing something like this:

```
module Kernel
    class << self
        alias :real_abort :abort
        def abort
            puts "press enter"
            gets
            puts "invoking real abort"
            real_abort
        end
    end
end
```

The reason IRB is invoking the original abort and not your defined `abort` is because the IRB repl has a abort method thats a C-language variant of it.

You can see it by doing `show-source` on pry

```
[1] pry(main)> show-source abort

From: process.c (C Method):
Owner: Kernel
Visibility: private
Number of lines: 22

VALUE
rb_f_abort(int argc, const VALUE *argv)
{
    rb_check_arity(argc, 0, 1);
    if (argc == 0) {
    if (!NIL_P(GET_THREAD()->errinfo)) {
        ruby_error_print();
    }
    rb_exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
    VALUE args[2];

    args[1] = args[0] = argv[0];
    StringValue(args[0]);
    rb_io_puts(1, args, rb_stderr);
    args[0] = INT2NUM(EXIT_FAILURE);
    rb_exc_raise(rb_class_new_instance(2, args, rb_eSystemExit));
    }

    UNREACHABLE;
}
```

In the code you mentioned the abort thats being executed is not Kernel.abort but the C-language abort thats mapped to IRB when you invoke it from commandline

If you want it to be masked you could do something like this so that the `abort` in IRB repl would execute your redefined `abort`

```
def abort; Kernel.abort; end
```

Then if you run `abort` it would invoke your redefined Kernel's abort singleton method.

Comment: I added an example to my answer which shows that the phenomenon is not due to the native method.

Comment: Down voter can you contradict my answer and say it's wrong??